# SQL Server XML Import - Is there a way to make the “value” operator return null on missing elements

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a stored proc that inserts XML into an underlying table.  Unfortunately the XML passed in as a Sql XML type sometimes has particular elements missing.  This makes the INSERT statement insert XML node values into the wrong columns.

My T-SQL looks something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_Test_Insert]
    @xmlData XML
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
TestTable
(
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  ColumnC
)
SELECT
    Tbl.Col.value(ColumnA[1]', 'INT'),
    Tbl.Col.value('ColumnB[1]', 'INT'),
    Tbl.Col.value('ColumnC[1]', 'INT')
 FROM
   @xmlData.nodes('DocumentElement/DataTable') Tbl(Col)
```

Sometimes ColumnB element may be missing in the XML structure.  This results in the ColumnC node value being inserted into the ColumnB table column.

Is there a way to make the “value” operator return null on missing elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably simplified your sample a bit too much. What you have here works as expected and will not insert ColumnC values to table ColumnA and missing ColumnB tags will give you a null value.

Try this:

```
declare @xmlData xml = '
<DocumentElement>
  <DataTable>
    <ColumnA>1</ColumnA>
    <ColumnC>3</ColumnC>
  </DataTable>
</DocumentElement>
'

SELECT
    Tbl.Col.value('ColumnA[1]', 'INT'),
    Tbl.Col.value('ColumnB[1]', 'INT'),
    Tbl.Col.value('ColumnC[1]', 'INT')
 FROM
   @xmlData.nodes('DocumentElement/DataTable') Tbl(Col)
```

Result:

```
----------- ----------- -----------
1           NULL        3
```

Comment: Yes I simplified the sample.  My XML structure actually contains 49 nodes.  I didn't want to clutter my question.  The underlying table I am trying to insert into allows NULLS on all columns.  The data types on the table columns are either VARCHAR(MAX), INT, DATETIME or BIT.

Comment: @MylesJ Is the entire element missing in the xml or are the element there but empty in the cases where you want null values?

Comment: The entire element is missing in the xml.

Comment: OK I feel embarrassed now!  The INSERT statement was wrong...one of the columns was in the wrong order.  Many thanks for your help anyway.  I will give you the answer.